# Use epoll_wait on boost UDP port

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio, epoll

I use boost UDP post. I init the socket and then call receive. it works fine.

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket soc1
...
soc1.receive(...)
```

What I want is to get some file descriptor from the socket and call epoll_wait myself:

```
epoll_wait(soc1.GetFileDescriptor())
if (has data)
    soc1.receive(...)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It might be possible, but what you are trying to do looks inherently incorrect from design point of view. What are you trying to achieve ? Maybe that will help us understand the intention and perhaps provide alternate solution.

Comment: I have many sockets, and want to avoid round robin between them and calling receive(). I would like to call epoll_wait, and then call receive() only on sockets that actually have data

Comment: That's what `io_service` is for. You should be able to pass an instance of `io_service` while creating the socket. The reactor service of the scheduler will do exactly what you are trying to do provided you provide a callback that needs to be executed on receiving data.